# Invisible Space preventing me from growing HD partition to original size

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

[image]

I want to restore my original Macintosh HD disk to its maximum size however in the partition map which should be 121.33GB it only adds up to 84GB. How can i get this "invisible" space back onto my Macintosh HD. [image]

Comment: Start by running the command `diskutil list`. Edit you question and add the output from this command.

Comment: I added the picture of the diskutil list command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OSXRESERVED` is create by the Boot Camp Assistant. This is suppose to contain the Windows installation files. You can remove this partition by entering the following.

```
sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
```

The free space can be added back to macOS by entering the following command.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: Thank you, i was under the impression it was an important partition for some System files, Solved,